# How to Refresh page after Response.End

Tags: asp.net, httpresponse

In my ASP.NET application on a button click i am writing a .pdf content dynamically and the I am allowing to download for a User

Now to download i used Response.End() and need to refresh a download count on a page 
But due to Response.End it is not happening

Please suggest

Comment: Can you give us your code sample?

Answer (score 3):

And it will never happen - You can not refresh page after `Response.End`

The way you download the files is not the best one. Use a handler for the download files and a simple anchor to that file.

Examples / Similar :
[file download by calling .ashx page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12087040/file-download-by-calling-ashx-page/12087222#12087222)
[What is the best way to download file from server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10912164/what-is-the-best-way-to-download-file-from-server/10912955#10912955)
[Hide modal window after Response.End() in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13295997/hide-modal-window-after-response-end-in-asp-net/13296135#13296135)